# How to merge a SpatRaster in one crs, extend to another crs, and then merge the extended

Tags: r, terra

I have multiple Sentinel-2 granules that extend across multiple UTM zones. I present a simple case of 2 zones (e.g., EPSG:32610 and EPSG:32609). I am looking for an effective way to mosaic or merge the SpatRasters to span across a larger geographic area.

The script provided has a couple of problems. First, this seems to be an overly complicated process and there must be a simpler way to handle this problem. This situation is likely to be encountered often for people wanting to mosaic or merge satellite images spanning across multiple UTM zones. Problems I encountered with using `resample()` and `project()` is that the resolution changes from 10 x 10 m to a slightly adjusted resolution with decimals (e.g., 10.01354 m x 10.02389 m); this makes sense.

Hence, the loop first places the CRS's of the SpatRasters in the directory into a dataframe `crss_r`. Next, I use a series of else if statements to list (a) the smaller CRS's that are in the east and (b) the larger CRS's that are in the west. The SpatRasters that share the same CRS in the east and those in the west are merged together (east merge, west merge). The east set to the extent of the polygon that is large enough to contain all the SpatRasters in the east and the west. This should permit a merge between east and west and a final crop to the polygon.

```
east1_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 687000, xmax = 688000, ymin = 6253400, ymax = 6254400, crs="EPSG:32609")
evals1 <- sample(c(-1:1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

east2_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 687500, xmax = 688500, ymin = 6253400, ymax = 6254400, crs="EPSG:32609")
evals2 <- sample(c(-1:1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

east3_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 689300, xmax = 690300, ymin = 6253400, ymax = 6254400, crs="EPSG:32609")
evals3 <- sample(c(-1:1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

west1_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 758600, xmax = 759600, ymin = 6290020, ymax = 6291020, crs="EPSG:32610")
wvals1 <- sample(c(-1:1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

west2_2021<- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 758800, xmax = 759800, ymin = 6290220, ymax = 6291220, crs="EPSG:32610")
wvals2 <- sample(c(-1:1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

west3_2021<- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 755800, xmax = 756800, ymin = 6288220, ymax = 6289220, crs="EPSG:32610")
wvals3 <- sample(c(-1:1), 1000, replace=TRUE)

values(east1_2021) <- evals1
values(east2_2021) <- evals2
values(east3_2021) <- evals3
values(west1_2021) <- wvals1
values(west2_2021) <- wvals2
values(west3_2021) <- wvals3

samp_rasters <- list()
samp_rasters[[1]] <- east1_2021
samp_rasters[[2]] <- east2_2021
samp_rasters[[3]] <- west1_2021
samp_rasters[[4]] <- west2_2021
samp_rasters[[5]] <- east3_2021
samp_rasters[[6]] <- west3_2021


E2021.list <- list()
E2021e.list <- list()
E2021w.list <- list()

crss_r <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(samp_rasters)){
  E2021.list[[i]] <- samp_rasters[[i]]
crss_r <- rbind(crss_r, as.numeric(crs(E2021.list[[i]], describe=TRUE)$code))
}

unique(crss_r)
#X32609
#1  32609
#4  32610

## Counters
  e = 1 # East counter
  w = 1 # West counter

  y = 1 # First in East
  z = 1 # First in West

  for(i in 1:length(samp_rasters)){
    
    if(crs(E2021.list[[i]], describe=TRUE)$code == 32609 & y == 1){
      e = 1
      E2021e.list[[e]] <- E2021.list[[i]]
      y <- y+1
    }
    
    else if(crs(E2021.list[[i]], describe=TRUE)$code == 32610 & z == 1){
      w = 1
      E2021w.list[[w]] <- E2021.list[[i]]
      z <- z+1
    }
    
    else if(crs(E2021.list[[i]], describe=TRUE)$code == 32609 & y != 1){
      e <- e+1
      E2021e.list[[e]] <- E2021.list[[i]]
    }

    else if(crs(E2021.list[[i]], describe=TRUE)$code == 32610 & z != 1){
      w <- w+1
      E2021w.list[[w]] <- E2021.list[[i]]
    }
  
    else{next}
  }

  ##E2021e <- sprc(E2021e.list) ## create a SpatRasterCollection east?
  ##E2021w <- sprc(E20212.list) ## create a SpatRasterCollection west? 
        
  E2021_east <- do.call(mosaic, E2021e.list)
  W2021_west <- do.call(mosaic, E2021w.list)
```

Example polygon [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vi1HsXAThf39hJoqq5qwhISy3hkF1CYs?usp=sharing) or using:
`ext(polygon.shp)`, I round up to nearest even digit:

```
#SpatExtent : 606452.305334048, 869193.508446992, 6145080.67822892, 6378308.32505462 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

  e <- ext(606500, 869200, 6145100, 6378400)


  E2020_eastext <- terra::extend(E2020_east, ext(e)) ##
  W2020_westext <- terra::extend(W2020_west, ext(e)) ##

  E2021_eastext <- terra::extend(E2021_east, ext(polygon.shp))
  W2021_westext <- terra::extend(W2021_west, ext(polygon.shp))
  
  Full_2021 <- merge(E2021_eastext, W2021_westext)
  
  Full_2021 <- crop(Full_2021, polygon.shp, mask=TRUE)
```

There is a problem in the final merge or mosaic using my actual data - the images from the different zones are in the wrong place (lakes in the east are mirrored with in the west).

Further, once the merge or mosaic aligns, I am curious to know if there a simpler way to accomplish this across zones? I have plans to run this larger geographic areas crossing more zones, which makes this process a little more convoluted than I would prefer.

[image: Merge image - notice lakes in east are also in west]

[image: Mosaic image - notice lakes in east are also in west]

[image: Raster in QGIS]

Comment: Not really possible to answer well without example data. Can you create some example data with code. That is use `rast( )` and use the extents and crs that you have, but use a much lower spatial resolution for the example (e.g. 10 km).

Comment: I've created example data. I don't know how to quickly create a sample polygon, so I created one that will work using QGIS and provided the link in the code comment. I actually re-ran the full code and just noticed that it only creates the east zone in the output - the east is not showing up properly.

Comment: Note in the example data - I get the following: > Full_2021 <- mosaic(E2021_eastext, W2021_westext)
Warning message:
[mosaic] rasters did not align and were resampled

Comment: I solved one issue by using project(x, y, align=TRUE). The alignment solved my problem of the different resolution, but it is very slow. I read <a href="https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/geometric-operations.html">here</a> that I had to extend first, but I don't think it is needed. I did not mention that the outputs are vegetation indices (not relevant), but gives context to the outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your example data. But the first question I would ask is how did you get into this mess? If you are using Sentinel data they should not all have different extents?

```
library(terra)
east1_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 687000, xmax = 688000, ymin = 6253400, ymax = 6254400, crs="EPSG:32609", vals=sample(c(-1:1), 100, replace=TRUE))
east2_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 687500, xmax = 688500, ymin = 6253400, ymax = 6254400, crs="EPSG:32609", vals=sample(c(-1:1), 100, replace=TRUE))
east3_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 689300, xmax = 690300, ymin = 6253400, ymax = 6254400, crs="EPSG:32609", vals=sample(c(-1:1), 100, replace=TRUE))
west1_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 758600, xmax = 759600, ymin = 6290020, ymax = 6291020, crs="EPSG:32610", vals=sample(c(-1:1), 100, replace=TRUE))
west2_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 758800, xmax = 759800, ymin = 6290220, ymax = 6291220, crs="EPSG:32610", vals=sample(c(-1:1), 100, replace=TRUE))
west3_2021 <- rast(ncols = 10, nrows = 10, xmin = 755800, xmax = 756800, ymin = 6288220, ymax = 6289220, crs="EPSG:32610", vals=sample(c(-1:1), 100, replace=TRUE))
samp_rasters <- list(east1_2021, east2_2021, east3_2021, west1_2021, west2_2021, west3_2021)
```

You have input data in UTM zones 9 and 10.

```
 sapply(samp_rasters, \(i)crs(i,proj=T)) |> unique()
 #[1] "+proj=utm +zone=9 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" 
 #[2] "+proj=utm +zone=10 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

What coordinate refer you would like the merged data to be in -- as it should normally not be either of the two (but see further below for the case where you pick one of the two). I will assume longitude/latitude.

```
outcrs <- "+proj=longlat"
```

The general approach could be to first make a template output raster. To make one, I first compute the extent of the input data.

```
fun <- function(r) {
    p <- as.polygons(r, extent=TRUE) 
    crds(project(p, outcrs))
}

xy <- do.call(rbind, lapply(samp_rasters, fun) ) |> apply(2, range)
e <- round(ext(as.vector(xy)) + 0.05 , 1)
e
#SpatExtent : -126, -118.7, 56.3, 56.7 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Use that extent, and choose a spatial resolution that matches the input data (100m ~ .01 degrees)

```
temp <- rast(e, res=.01, crs=outcrs) 
temp
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 40, 730, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
#extent      : -126, -118.7, 56.3, 56.7  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

Now project all rasters to the output template

```
y <- lapply(samp_rasters, \(x) project(x, temp))
```

And merge the results

```
z <- merge(rast(y[1:3]), rast(y[4:6]))
names(z) <- paste0("step", 1:3)
z
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 40, 730, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
#extent      : -126, -118.7, 56.3, 56.7  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source      : memory 
#names       :       step1,       step2,       step3 
#min values  : -0.68459326, -0.08613852, -0.99006349 
#max values  :   0.0181742,   0.6328486,  -0.1931030
```

Which you could also do with `tapp` like this (this is actually the same as `mosaic`, but that is the same as `merge` if there are no overlapping values)

```
zz <- tapp(rast(y), rep(1:3, 2), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
names(zz) <- paste0("step", 1:3)
```

But note that once you have a template, you can take a shortcut with `impose`

```
e <- impose(sprc(samp_rasters[1:3]), temp)
w <- impose(sprc(samp_rasters[4:6]), temp)
m <- merge(e, w)
```

(For efficiency you could use different templates for different zones, by cropping the relevant part of the entire region template)

You should not need `extend` for any of this as `merge` (or alternatively `mosaic`) can take care of this.

If you want to see the results you need to first aggregate the values, because in this example there are two small areas with values with a very large zone of nothing in between.

```
a <- aggregate(m, 100, mean, na.rm=T)
plot(a,1)
```

---

*An alternative scenario.* You may have a situation where you want to keep the crs of one of the two sources. With UTM that is generally not a good idea because you might get a lot of distortion. But it can be reasonable if data covered by one zone is not far outside the area of another. In this case, you can do

```
outcrs <- crs(samp_rasters[[1]])
xy <- do.call(rbind, lapply(samp_rasters, fun) ) |> apply(2, range)
e <- round(ext(as.vector(xy)))
temp <- rast(e, res=100, crs=outcrs) 
e <- impose(sprc(samp_rasters[1:3]), temp)
w <- impose(sprc(samp_rasters[4:6]), temp)
m <- merge(e, w)
m
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 767, 4391, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 100, 100  (x, y)
#extent      : 687000, 1126100, 6253400, 6330100  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : WGS 84 / UTM zone 9N (EPSG:32609) 
#source      : memory 
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.1, lyr.1 
#min values  :    -1,    -1,    -1 
#max values  :     1,     1,     1
```

Comment: Thank you for the very informative response. Other data from this project is in UTM, so I was keeping things consistent. The actual Sentinel-2 data does not have different extents (you are correct) - I created smaller extents in the example data within the extents of my data. Terra is a wonderful package and your response helps to clarify a couple of things I can use to better organize my code. Everything is working great.